# Is there a way to pull lists of values from lists of objects in R?

Tags: r, list, object

I am trying to create a sublist from a list of objects based on the value of one of their elements. For example, I create a object class with:

```
setClass("Foo",representation(Attrib = "vector"))
```

Then I create a list of objects of this class:

```
CreateData = function() { new("Foo",Attrib=sample(0:1,5,replace=TRUE)) }
FooSet = CreateData()
for(i in 1:20) { FooSet=c(FooSet,CreateData()) }
```

Now I want to create a subset of the list containing the set where the first element of Attrib is one. Ideally I would do this by saying:

```
FooSubset = FooSet[FooSet@Attrib[1] == 1]
```

However, this results in a error, as FooSet[i] is a list of one object, rather than the object itself; to get the object, I would need to do FooSet[[i]]. Is there a simple way to get the logical index vector to check the object element appropriately, or some other method of doing this short of a for loop?

Comment: To clarify that last bit,
FooSet[1]@Attrib[1]
generates the error:
Error: trying to get slot "Attrib" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots.
On the other hand,
FooSet[[1]]@Attrib[1]
generates a value, for my test a 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply()` in the index.  It's still a loop, but you have a list so you're going to have to have a loop to grab elements.

```
FooSet[sapply(FooSet, slot, "Attrib")[1, ] == 1]
```

or

```
FooSet[sapply(FooSet, function(x) x@Attrib[1]) == 1]
```